# Java VolatileImage Intel integrated graphic no more supported?

Tags: java, graphics, volatile, integrated

I' ve wrote myself a litte ken burns slider and it worked quite well with the intel integrated graphic. I do not know which version of the driver I used and I just tried old java versions first, but it seems to be a driver problem or something else. I can force open gl at startup to make it work in window mode now... but that is not a solution. Tried on a couple of systems (all windows)... always the same. Next step would be to get clear about if it is the driver ... but I don t like to. Hope you know how to fix it. Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... the answer was already there. I was just disappointed about the fact that it had worked before without changing any parameters. set J2D_D3D_NO_HWCHECK=true does the job - it is accelerated again. thanks guys - peace and love - if you like you can delete the post.

Actually it fix(e)s it... but maybe anyone can give further information? What kind of check is this? And why did it turn worse?